# How can I make this layout on Android?

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager to swipeing images in layout. But I want to that this is looking differently.

I would like to: On the right side of the screen the next image is displaying a little, and the left side of the screen the previous image is displaying. How can I make it?

Here it is a picture to show what I am imagining: http://img2.myimg.de/zZIKS7c048.jpg

And how can I use ViewPager in subpart of the screen?

Comment: Any attempts or code snippets?
BTW: the link throws a 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) to implement view pager. And to show view pager in subpart you can set its width and height like this

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```